# Get count only all parameters are within there LSL & USL

Tags: excel

From below data table, I tried to get sample count which are each value within their specification limits. To get the sample count, all 3 values must fulfilled its specification requirement. I used SUMPRODUCT function for each and every column and checked its relevant specification limits using following formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B3:B8>=B9)*(B3:B8<=B10),(C3:C8>=C9)*(C3:C8<=C10),(D3:D8>=D9)*(D3:D8<=D10))
```

But when I am dealing with more columns, this is getting more complex.
My question is, are there any other way to check all column at once? to reduce the formula complexity.

[image]

Note:- Highlighted with red color are out of specification limits. Only 2 & 6 rows are counted the returned result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT`/`MMULT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MMULT((B3:D8>=B9:D9)*(B3:D8<=B10:D10),ROW(A1:A3)^0)=3))
```

Just remember that the second parameter of `MMULT` must specify the number of rows corresponding to the number of columns of the first parameter, i.e. `B3:D8` = 3 columns => `A1:A3` = 3 rows. The comparison with `3` also changes accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Great this is doing exactly what I want. This is the first time I am using MMULT function Thank you for your support.